# Horizontal space between math mode and punctuation

Tags: spacing, punctuation

In the following minimal example, the first version is what I would normally type.  However, for my taste the space between the T and the comma is too large.  The other three versions look better to me, but I'm not quite sure how to deal with this in a general way.  For the second version, I guess that depending on the font used I can't really be sure whether the math T is the same as the normal italic T.  The third version seems like a kludge.  Is there a recommended way to deal with this or is the general wisdom that the first line looks OK?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Let $x$ be an element of $T$, let $y$ be something else.
\item Let $x$ be an element of \textit{T}, let $y$ be something else.
\item Let $x$ be an element of $T\!$, let $y$ be something else.
\item Let $x$ be an element of $T,$ let $y$ be something else.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Use item 1. Surely not `\textit{T}`. The small negative space might look appealing (but not to me). About item 4, the comma is *not* part of the formula.

Answer (score 3):

2 is wrong, the math T is not the same as text italic T, and logically distorting the markup that much would be wrong even in font setups where these are the same

3 is sort of OK, although I probably wouldn't bother

4 looks Ok but logically the comma isn't part of the math and the math font typically isn't the same as the text font so you are relying on commas being small and hope the font difference isn't noticable.

so 1 or 3....

Comment: Regarding 4, I'm aware that the comma isn't part of the math, but it is general practice to put punctuation into displayed formulas, isn't it?

Comment: if I end a displayed formula with a sentence-level punctuation I'd use `\text{;}` so that the current text font was used, but `$T\text{,}$` wouldn't help you at all. @Frunobulax